# How should I lubricate a hinge that does not have a removable pin?

Tags: doors, old-house, hinges

I live in a house with some very old hardware, including these hinges which have started to squeak. The hinges don't appear to have a removable pin, as both of the end knuckles seem to be completely enclosed. I cannot locate any sort of seam or gap to remove the pin.
**From the side:**
[image: My hinge, from the side]

**From above:**
[image: My hinge, from above]

**From below:**
[image: My hinge, from below]

The hinges seem to resemble these, which I found while poking around online:
[image: Similar hinges, found online]

How can I oil hinges like this? Do I need to take them off the door/frame? At that point, should I just replace the hinges? For what it's worth, the house is two hundred years old, although I highly doubt these hinges are.

Comment: there is always a pin, sometime visible and easy to remove sometimes not

Comment: @Ruskes well, it may become visible, but that doesn't mean it's removable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Hold some newspaper or paper towel below a hinge.
- Apply a fairly thin oil to the hinge, mostly aiming at the top joint
  (it will, of course, drip down.)
- Open and close the door several times to move the hinge while oil is present.
- Wipe up any excess oil.
- Repeat until all hinges are oiled, and as needed if squeaking persists.

It's possible, but I lack adequate experience with whether the lubricant really flows as an oil does before "drying" that dry lube as sold for bicycle chains might also work here. Whatever you use needs to creep/wick between the barrels and along the pin, so anything that becomes immobile too quickly won't work.

Comment: You thinking Tri-Flow?

Answer (score 1):

I just put some machine oil on the top outside of the hinge. Put enough so some will dribble down the length of the hinge. Open and close the door and the oil will wick itself between the bearing surfaces. Once the squeaking stops, wipe off the excess.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the condition of current hardware, I would replace them and not worry about the pin.

As temporary squeaking stop, I had success with WD40.

Have some paper towel ready to prevent dripping on the floor and making stains.